# What's the best way to render a mixture of html and plain text in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, whitespace, removing-whitespace

On my site users can create posts with a mixture of plain text and html. I'm having trouble rendering their posts nicely.

E.g., they might write:

```
This is the first line of the post.

<!-- whitespace 1 -->

<ul>
<li>List item 1.</li>

<!-- whitespace 2 -->

<li>List item 2.</li>
<li>List item 3.</li>
</ul>
<!-- whitespace 3 -->
This is the last line of the post.
```

and I want whitespace 1 and 3 to render, but not whitespace 2. How can I do this?

I've tried using a combination of `linebreaks` and `spaceless` but cannot get it to work.

Thanks

Jack

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do, but you might be able to use `regex`. Something like `<!--\s\w+\s[13]\s-->`

Comment: Why don't you want whitespace 2 to render? Because it's within an unordered list?

Comment: I want to force lists to all appear the same, i.e., evenly spaced on my site.

Comment: If you don't use the `linebreaks` filter when rendering somebody's post, then plain text (which was separated) gets bunched together. So you need to use `linebreaks`. However, if you use `linebreaks` and your post includes html, `<br>` tags replace newlines between html tags and this would cause ugly gaps between the list items in the example above.

Comment: You could use this pattern to grab everything within list tags [`(?s)(?<=<[uo]l>).*(?=<\/[ou]l>)`](https://regex101.com/r/7aWoRG/1), then use another regex pattern `<br>`  to see if any <br> tags exist within that. If they do reject the input.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I've never really used regex. Could you explain a little more how I would use the above code?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, you can use regex to get a collection of matches for the contents of each list, and then check those contents to make sure they don't contain any `<br>` tags. To gather the contents of your list elements you can use this pattern [`(?s)(?<=<[ou]l>).*?(?=<\/[ou]l>)`](https://regex101.com/r/7aWoRG/2).

Once you have a collection of matches using `re.findall("(?s)(?<=<[ou]l>).*?(?=<\/[ou]l>)", inputstring)`, you can do something like this:

```
for m in matches:
  if not re.match("<br>", m):
    #input is fine
  else:
    #lists cannot contain <br> tags
```

This rejects input that contains lists with `<br>` tags in them.

To explain the pattern,
`(?s)` makes it so `.` matches new line characters as well

`(?<=<[ou]l>)` means the pattern must start with either `<ol>` or `<ul>`

`.*?` means capture everything up until the next part of the pattern

`(?=<\/[ou]l>)` means the pattern is followed by either `</ol>` or `</ul>`